# How to prevent R from slowing down in long analysis besides freeing up memory?

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection

Apologies in advance if this is a slightly abstract question.

I have some modular data analysis code that in the abstract goes something like this:

```
source("load_analysis_settings.R")

source("load_and_clean_data.R")

source("analyse_data.R")
```

The analysis in `analyse_data.R` actually runs on hundreds of subsets of the data, using a `for` loop (unfortunately there are too many steps, and too complicated, for me to successfully parallelise using `apply`, including fitting some `brms` models).

When I try to do this in one sitting, R/RStudio quickly runs out of memory (or something, I don't know enough about what's going on under the hood) and slows to a crawl, and it can take literally days to run.

The workaround I've used so far is to manually break up the hundreds of subsets of data into more manageable chunks, saving the output periodically, restarting R/RStudio to run the next chunk, and then recombining them all at the end. Basically:

```
source("load_analysis_settings.R")

source("load_and_clean_data.R")

subset_data_to_part_1

source("analyse_data.R")

save_analysis_output_part_1
```

(Rinse and repeat for part 2, 3, etc. until done, then manually recombine at the end)

This is *much* faster than trying to do it all at once (e.g. I could run 4 parts in 3 hours each, 12 hours total, where trying to do them all at once would take about 48-72 hours). However, it requires manual intervention through restarting RStudio and incrementing the part # between running each part.

In effect, I'm manually functioning as an overarching `for` loop:

```
for (part in 1:length(parts)) {
    specify_part_settings
    run_analysis_code
    manually_restart_R
}

recombine_results
```

I'm wondering if there's some way to automate this process with an *actual* `for` loop so it doesn't require manual intervention for restarting. Incrementing the settings is easy, but I don't know how to get the speed benefits of actually restarting (memory-clearing? dunno what else is going on) with each iteration. I can add `remove` for any large outputs and `gc()` into the overarching loop. But I've tried using `gc()` in the workflow before and it doesn't seem to help that much.

What else is going on memory-wise when RStudio restarts, and how could I get those actions into the overarching `for` loop? or is there a way to build an actual restart into it?

Comment: It's far too much speculation to know what's causing a memory bloom in code we cannot see, unfortunately. A common mistake in users new to R is iteratively adding rows to frames using something like `for (...) { ..., dat <- rbind(dat, newdat); }`, this is bad practice and always slows more and more as the iterations grow. I don't know if that's at all what's happening with you. If not, please add more context/code to your question. I recognize that you say it's a lot of complicated code, so this may just be outside the scope of SO if you're not able to reduce it enough. Good luck!

Comment: One way to do automatic restarts is to do the looping outside of R.  Use a shell script or other scripting tool to run many times, each time passing some value to it that corresponds to `part`.

Comment: Thank @r2evans - can provide more info later but no, I initialise an empty vector as a container for the results, like `iter_out <- vector("list", <length>)` , assign the results from each go around the loop like `iter_out[[i]] <- results`, and then bind it at the end, like `combined_result <- bind_rows(iter_out)`

So I don't think the writing problem is it?

Comment: Probably not, I think you're guarding against that. Sorry, it was a stab in the dark.

Comment: @user2554330 yeah, have considered doing that, trying to see if there's a solution (or approximate solution) within R

Comment: The usual guess for why such a thing happens is memory fragmentation.  There might be lots of free memory after each loop, but none of it is suitable for the next allocation, so R needs to grab more.  The fix is to do all allocation at the start.  Don't just allocate a list, allocate a data.frame (or even better, a matrix) to hold all the results, then fill it in as you go.  This can be hard to do when iteration results vary in size; then maybe guess at the final size, and reallocate if you really have to, then throw away extras at the end.

Comment: You might also want to look at the [`subprocess`](http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/subprocess/vignettes/intro.html) package - basically it's the same logic as using a shell script to call each individual R script, but instead you're spawning child R processes from a parent R script, which might be easier if you're passing parameters between processes.

Comment: @user2554330 hmm, okay. The final output is a tibble (working with `tidyverse`) that is created from the `bind_rows` command on the list (see my other comment above); are you suggesting instead of initialising an empty list, I initialise an empty tibble with the necessary columns instead?

Comment: @SamR thanks, I'll take a look! I'm somewhat familiar with `subprocess` in Python (and that's what would've been my go-to solution for an 'outside R' option) but had no idea something like that existed in R.

Comment: @TYLim:  Yes, that was the suggestion.  Another suggestion:  don't use tibbles/dataframes, use matrices.  They are much faster for most operations, at a cost of making it more complicated to deal with mixed types (since each matrix can have only one type).  Dataframes are great if you are mainly working with whole columns, but it sounds like you aren't.